# Angular Routing and click function executing at the same time

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a component.html page like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 offset-xs-4 offset-sm-4 offset-md-4 offset-lg-4 offset-xl-4">
      <button  type="button" (click)="getValuesFromForm()" routerLink="/AnotherComponent"  [disabled]="!loginform.valid" class="btn btn-outline-danger col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 form-control ">Submit</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

In component.ts I have the following code

```
getValuesFromForm()
{
   console.log("GetVAluesFromForm Executed");
}
```

Now I want to execute the function and then want to redirect to another Component.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **router.navigate**

```
<button  type="button" (click)="getValuesFromForm()"  [disabled]="!loginform.valid" class="btn btn-outline-danger col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 form-control ">Submit</button>


getValuesFromForm() {
  this.router.navigate(['/AnotherComponent']);
}
```

Where router is service provided by RouterModule and you can create router variable as

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router:Router){}
```

Comment: [ts] Argument of type '"/AnotherComponent"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.

Comment: I have added private router: Router in the constructor. And import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router'; in the component also.

Comment: Use ['/AnotherComponent'] . Sorry My bad.

Comment: And in the above solution you have mentioned import { Router } from 'angular/router'; you have to give @angular/router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160202/discussion-between-roopteja-and-ankit-kapoor).